# Issue in Converting my Project from D7 to XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I've now decided to convert my Delphi 7 project to XE4 , But in One of my Code lines i get an issue of witch i tried to Fix it but with no Hope , So i wish someone can help me in Fixing It .

Here's the issue :

In a Shared Unit used between a Server and Client App ( hotel rooms management system ) i have this Record type:

```
      Type
      THotelClientDetails = packed record
      LSize:  Integer;
      ClientName:  array[0..25] of char;
      ClientRoomN:  Integer;
      RWithInternet: Boolean;
      RoomStatus    :Integer;
    //... etc 
      end;
          PHotelClientDetails = ^THotelClientDetails;
```

In the Client App i use the follwing Procedure :

```
procedure TCForm.SendClientDetailsClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  pClientDetails: PHotelClientDetails;
  iSize: Integer;
  begin

  iSize:= SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)+Length(ClientNameEd.Text)+1;
  GetMem(pClientDetails,iSize);
  ZeroMemory(pClientDetails,iSize);
  pClientDetails.LSize := iSize;
  StrCopy(pClientDetails.ClientName,PChar(ClientNameEd.Text));
  pClientDetails.ClientRoomN  :=StrToInt(ClientNEd.text);
  pClientDetails.RWithInternet:=ClientWInternet.Checked;
  pClientDetails.RoomStatus   :=ClientRoomStatus.ItemIndex;
  StrCopy(Pointer(Cardinal(pClientDetails)+SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)),
  PChar(ClientNameEd.Text));
  SendClientsBuffer(pClientDetails,iSize);// to the Server for Check
  FreeMem(pClientDetails);

  end;
```

And in the Server App i use the Following Procedure :

```
Procedure TSForm.GetClientDetails(pClientDetails:PHotelClientDetails; Cntx: Pointer);
  var
  ClientName: string;
  begin
  ClientName:=PChar(Cardinal(pClientDetails)+SizeOf(THotelClientDetails));
  //*** just a test to get the ClientName
  ShowMessage(ClientName);
  //***
  end;
```

So my problem is when using Delphi 7 i get the full name sent by the Client App :
for example if i want to send the Client " simon  " or "matthew" to the Server

i get the correct name in :

```
ShowMessage(ClientName);//simon or matthew
```

But when using the same Procedures in XE4 i always get

**sim**  for **simon** 
and 
**matt** for **matthew**

that means the Server is not receiving the full Client's Name as with Delphi7 project .

Although is added the unit " System.AnsiStrings; " in Both Projects .

So please how can i fix this Issue ?

and So many thanks .

Simon

Comment: `ClientName:  array[0..25] of AnsiChar;`

Comment: @bummi thank you i used it but i always get this compiler error :
`code
E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrCopy' that can be called with these arguments `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi 7 uses ANSI strings (single-byte Chars), while versions of Delphi from 2009 and up use Unicode strings  (multi-byte Chars).

The most straightforward fix for your code is to change from `Char` to `AnsiChar`, `string` to `AnsiString`, and `PChar` to `PAnsiChar`:

```
Type
  THotelClientDetails = packed record
    LSize:  Integer;
    ClientName:  array[0..25] of AnsiChar;
    ClientRoomN:  Integer;
    RWithInternet: Boolean;
    RoomStatus    :Integer;
    //... etc 
  end;

StrCopy(pClientDetails.ClientName, PAnsiChar(ClientNameEd.Text));
// and
StrCopy(Pointer(Cardinal(pClientDetails) + SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)),
        PAnsiChar(ClientNameEd.Text));

Procedure TSForm.GetClientDetails(pClientDetails:PHotelClientDetails; Cntx: Pointer);
var
  ClientName: string;
begin
  ClientName := PAnsiChar(Cardinal(pClientDetails)+SizeOf(THotelClientDetails));
  //*** just a test to get the ClientName
  ShowMessage(ClientName);
  //***
end;
```

There are literally dozens (if not hundreds) of questions relating to porting Delphi code from D2007 and earlier to D2009 and later here. You should spend some time browsing the [delphi-2009](/questions/tagged/delphi-2009), [delphi-xe](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe), and [delphi-xe2](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe2) tags here.

Comment: should i add the unit " System.AnsiStrings " to both projects ?

Comment: A quick test seems to say you won't need it. `var Test: AnsiString; begin SetLength(Test, 10); StrCopy(PAnsiChar(Test), PAnsiChar('Tested')); ShowMessage(Test);end;`

Comment: i edited my code as you told me but now i get s for simon and m  for mathew ... so many thanks for your help

Comment: I can't see your changes from here, so I don't know what you did; I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: if i don't add the unit System.AnsiStrings i see that StrCopy needs Dest and Source as PWideChar ?

Comment: I don't understand. If you're so sure you need to add `System.AnsiStrings`, **add it**. Just change the calls for `StrCopy` to `AnsiStrings.StrCopy` instead to make sure that version is the one being used.

Comment: Any way so many thanks Sir Ken , i will do all my best to get it work 
And again many thanks for this Starting Point .

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an answer because it easier to format than comments to the question.

Some remarks on things you might want do:

1. With the Unicode support in Delphi 2009 and up, do not assume that `Length` will get you the actual number of bytes of a string.
2. In between Delphi 7 an XE4 the concept op methods on records have been introduced (I think in Delphi 2006). Move parts of the logic `SendClientDetailsClick` into methods of `THotelClientDetails`
3. Since `THotelClientDetails.ClientName` is limited to 26 bytes (25 `AnsiChar` character bytes plus a null terminating byte), there is no need for
     `iSize:= SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)+Length(ClientNameEd.Text)+1;`
   Which means that `iSize:= SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)`.
4. The only reason you have a pointer `pClientDetails: PHotelClientDetails` is that you call
     `SendClientsBuffer(pClientDetails,iSize);// to the Server for Check`
   which you can replace by
     `SendClientsBuffer(ClientDetails,iSize);// to the Server for Check`
5. There is no length guard to prevent copying of more than 25 bytes in
   `StrCopy(pClientDetails.ClientName,PChar(ClientNameEd.Text));`
   Use [StrLCopy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrLCopy) there, not [StrCopy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrCopy).
6. Why are you performing a copy action from `ClientNameEd` twice?
   `StrCopy(pClientDetails.ClientName,PChar(ClientNameEd.Text));`
   `//...`
   `StrCopy(Pointer(Cardinal(pClientDetails)+SizeOf(THotelClientDetails)),
   PChar(ClientNameEd.Text));`
7. If you insist on pointers, the `FreeMem` should be in a `finally` block.

Something like this is more appropriate:

```
procedure TCForm.SendClientDetailsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ClientDetails: PHotelClientDetails;
  iSize: Integer;
begin
  iSize := SizeOf(THotelClientDetails);
  ZeroMemory(@ClientDetails, iSize);
  ClientDetails.LSize := iSize;
  StrLCopy(ClientDetails.ClientName, PAnsiChar(ClientNameEd.Text), SizeOf(ClientDetails.ClientName)-1);
  pClientDetails.ClientRoomN   := StrToInt(ClientNEd.text);
  pClientDetails.RWithInternet := ClientWInternet.Checked;
  pClientDetails.RoomStatus    := ClientRoomStatus.ItemIndex;
  SendClientsBuffer(@ClientDetails,iSize); // to the Server for Check
end;
```